# Composer memory limit error on update ( AWS Lightsail)

Tags: composer

I'm running an AWS lightsail server for a Drupal 8 qa site. I'm getting an out of memory error when running update. I created a new server with 2GB of memory, and was able to run updates for a few weeks, now I'm getting this:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///opt/bitnami/php/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52
```

I set the env var `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1`, didn't help.

The only major change I made since the last time it worked was using display suite for one content type, but ds had already been enabled previously. Seems like 2GB should be plenty, any suggestions on what to try?

Comment: If your server only has 2GB of memory and composer wants to use that or more, it will not be enough. Most are going to tell you not to run composer in production for various reasons.

Comment: I would not consider 2 GB "plenty".  On a cheap server with 4 GB of RAM I routinely ran out of memory; I have run out with 8 GB as well.  One fix is to use `git` and do all your composer stuff locally, commit, and push it to the host server.

Comment: Instead of using COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 as env variable, try with `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require drupal/MODULE_NAME` works for me.

Comment: Thanks to all for the suggestions. Turns out I have 4GB available, but php.ini limited it to 2GB. Changing it solved the problem.

Comment: Kevin, this brings up a bigger question; I this is a qa server for a site that won't relaunched until next month. My research tells me it is considered best practice to run composer on a local server and not keep core in git (my git just contains the composer.json and .lock files). After pulling to my qa server, I then run `composer update` to update the core files. Are you suggesting it would be better to keep everything in git? Seems it would be easier that way, and I would have to deal with the weirdness that composer sometimes has.

Comment: I don't know why people have such issues with composer, I've ran a dozen plus projects in the last few years with a build service without running composer on production servers. You should not run composer on production, and no, do not commit vendor managed dependencies. GitHub, GitLab etc all now provide the means of building a project and deploying it.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. If I don't commit vendor managed dependencies, what is the best way update them on production? I see there is a Git Deploy module, but it uses git.